# Why is Tensorflow sending me this error during the retrain process "can't open file 'tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py': "

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, tensorflow, classification

I'm currently using Tensorflow to make an image classifier and during the retrain process I keep getting an error after entering these lines.

```
python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
--bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks \
--how_many_training_steps 500 \
--model_dir=/tf_files/inception \
--output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
--output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
--image_dir /tf_files/flowers
```

The error this returns is -

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents
/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py':
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Im unsure if it's because I didn't install tensorflow correctly, or I'm missing some installation. I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

I'm also running python 2.7. -

```
Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 29 2018, 17:49:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you don't have that file, try downloading it from [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py)